# Выдает ошибку Недопустимый символ ""

Tags: c#

Выдает ошибку Недопустимый символ "" в строке, в которой этого даже нет, может следующая, но там без этого никак

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string line = textBox1.Text​;​ //в этой строке пишет, что ошибка

            string firstNewLine="", secondNewLine="";
            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0){
                    firstNewLine = line[i].ToString();
                } else {
                    secondNewLine = line[i].ToString();
                }
            }

            textBox2.Text += "Первая строка: " + firstNewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            textBox2.Text += "Вторая строка: " + secondNewLine;
        }
```

Comment: Задание было таким:
Сформировать и вывести две новых строки на основе входной строки
символов. В первую строку включить все символы, стоящие на четных местах, во 
вторую – символы, стоящие на нечетных местах в исходной строке

Comment: Привет. Не добавляйте пояснения к вопросу в комментариях, а редактируйте сам вопрос (ссылка под вопросом "Править"). Ошибка возникает при первом выполнении кода или при вторичном? Выведите значение в консоль. Посмотрите, что Вы используете в качестве начального значения в дизайнере форм.

Comment: В данном коде не вижу причин для возникновения указанной ошибки.

Comment: @XelaNimed, а это пояснение разве имеет отношение к вопросу?

Comment: @aepot, а я вижу. Сообщение прям явно намекает на непечатные символы в строке, и, если её скопировать, то они там есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy если не секрет, то как Вы обнаружили эти символы? Копирую, вставляю в Notepad++, отображение всех символов включено - ничего нет.

Comment: @XelaNimed, скопировал в devtools хрома - он прям при вводе показал точки. А вообще, т. к. я их собирался искать, я планировал сделать `[..."smth"].map(x => x.charCodeAt(0))` чтобы увидеть подозрительные коды.

Comment: @XelaNimed В любом языке перебираете эту строку посимвольно и печатаете коды символов. Я в Питоне проверял, например.

Answer (score 6):

Удали эти скрытые символы (у обоих код 0x200B - [пробел нулевой ширины](https://unicode-table.com/ru/200B/)):

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Защита на сайте от копирования кода?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, только в одной строке? Странно как-то. К тому же, очень сомневаюсь, что этот код копировался.